# How can I replace or remove country stroke color on hover Google Geo Charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Geo Chart with world countries and I'm trying to remove the stroke color when user hover the country. Default stroke color is gray 
and I found how to replace the country edge color, but for the hover event it does not write anything in the documentation.

How is looking now with stroke color on hover:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQuw5.jpg - Gray stroke for active countries

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x64kr.jpg - White stroke for inactive countries

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
data.addRows(countriesData);

var options = {
    sizeAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxSize: 100
    },
    colorAxis: {
        colors: colors
    },
    legend: 'none',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    keepAspectRatio: true,
    tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map'));
chart.draw(data, options);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var countries = document.getElementById('map').getElementsByTagName('path');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(countries, function (path) {
        path.setAttribute('stroke', '#d2b9df');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you've found, there is no standard config option.

when a country is made active, new `<path>` elements are added for that country.

we can use a `MutationObserver` to know when new elements have been added.

similar to your function to change the stroke color for inactive countries,
we use a `MutationObserver` to change the stroke color for active countries.

the `MutationObserver` will give us the added elements,
we just have to dig down to find the actual `<path>` elements.

```
// change active stroke color, build mutation observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (nodes) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
    // check for new nodes
    if (node.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.addedNodes, function(addedNode) {
        // the tooltip element will also be here, we only want the group elements
        if (addedNode.tagName === 'g') {
          // find children of the group element
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(addedNode.childNodes, function(childNode) {
            // check for path element, change stroke
            if (childNode.tagName === 'path') {
              childNode.setAttribute('stroke', '#ff0000');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

// activate mutation observer
observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'value'],
    ['United States', 1],
    ['Canada', 1],
  ]);

  var options = {
    sizeAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxSize: 100
    },
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#8a4cab', '#8a4cab']
    },
    legend: 'none',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    keepAspectRatio: true,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('map');
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // change inactive stroke color
    var countries = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(countries, function (path) {
      path.setAttribute('stroke', '#d2b9df');
    });

    // change active stroke color, build mutation observer
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (nodes) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
        // check for new nodes
        if (node.addedNodes.length > 0) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.addedNodes, function(addedNode) {
            // the tooltip element will also be here, we only want the group elements
            if (addedNode.tagName === 'g') {
              // find children of the group element
              Array.prototype.forEach.call(addedNode.childNodes, function(childNode) {
                // check for path element, change stroke
                if (childNode.tagName === 'path') {
                  childNode.setAttribute('stroke', '#ff0000');
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });

    // activate mutation observer
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

when made active, two path elements are added,
one with a black stroke and width of 3,
and another with the highlight color and width of 1.

check the stroke attribute and remove the black node...

```
            // check for path element, remove shadow, change stroke
            if (childNode.tagName === 'path') {
              if (childNode.getAttribute('stroke') === '#000000') {
                addedNode.removeChild(childNode);
              } else {
                childNode.setAttribute('stroke', '#ff0000');
              }
            }
```

Comment: The country still have a shadow when I hover on it. How can I remove that ?

Comment: see __EDIT__ above, my eyesight isn't great, I couldn't really notice the shadow, but two elements are added. either remove the one with a black stroke, as in the edit, or change the black stroke to transparent.

Comment: Awesome, I use it with `childNode.setAttribute('stroke', 'transparent');` if stroke color is black. Thank you again :)